Generating a clear sinusoidal wave through the oscillator to generate the "Ding Dong" sound
I am working on a project to try to recreate a close replica of the "Ding Dong" doorbell sound. I have yet to make the decay. (I would definitely appreciate if you have tips for that.)
I am currently struggling getting one or the other sounds to work and I'm not really sure what is happening. Osc1 just doesn't make any sounds unless I switch R11 to 200, and it still won't make any sounds till I change R9 to 200.
This is the image of my circuit, I'm not sure how to upload it:


What value was it when it didn't work? Have you tried looking at the DC voltages on the outputs when the value changes?

Please post a larger schematic and the .ASC file.

I see 2 squarewave oscillators, but no sinewave oscillators.  Also, it looks like U1, U2, and U3 are functioning as logic gates to enable the two oscillators.  Is this correct?  Please update your question with the frequencies of the oscillators and V2.

Be prepared for some disappointment with the sound of a sine wave. Bells and chimes have a lot of harmonics of their fundamental frequencies and these give their rich characteristic sound.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

user36, Use an MCU and look up Linear Predictive Coding. It's a good fit for the application. You may need to partition the LP coefficients. But that's not a problem. It's a feature for a case like this.

Here is my. ASC file. apologies for delays. file
The only issue is for our project, we are supposed to build this just out of capacitors, resistors, op amps, leds, and speakers. We can't use any other logic chips or anything of the sort.

What is the purpose of pulse source V2?

V2 is supposed to simulate a thermistor that I will be using when building the circuit physically. It is supposed to be the trigger for the ding dong sound. Both the Ding and Dong sounds should have oscillation, a Clear sinusoid, and a proper decay but I have yet to figure out the decay part since I'm still struggling with the earlier bit.

You should be aware that you can't get a doorbell "ding-dong" from just a pair of sinewave generators. In addition to the existance of harmonics, you need roughly an exponential encelope generator for each note.

@user369928 Your ASC file gets a 404 error for me.

I see 2 squarewave oscillators, but no sinewave oscillators. Also, it looks like U1, U2, and U3 are functioning as logic gates to enable the two oscillators. Is this correct? Please update your question with the frequencies of the oscillators and V2.
For U2, you have the non-inverting input tied to GND and the inverting input tied to 0 V when R6 equals R11.  Thus, the two inputs are almost perfectly equal and there is no negative feedback, so the output can be just about anything.  This is partly determined by the input offset voltage.  Decreasing R11 gives the opamp a distinct voltage difference between the two inputs, so the output has a clearly defined state.
Another issue is the output voltage range, listed as +/-2.5 V when powered by +/-15 V.  Unfortunately there is no chart relating peak output voltage versus Vcc, but it probably is close to the 15 V values for the entire operating voltage range.  That is, the output can swing to within 2.5 V of each rail.  So if the rails are +/-4.5 V, expect a max peak-to-peak output voltage range of +/-2 V.  That probably will require changing some components values to get the amps to switch states as desired.
It looks like both oscillators are enabled and disabled at the same time, so that will not produce separate ding and dong tones.
I think you can replace the vast majority of components in the schematic with a quad Schmitt trigger NAND gate such as the CD1093 or 74HC132.

These are my values after changing R11 to 500, U2 is green, U1 is red, and U3 is blue.: link
These are the values before the change, same colors: link
Also, I completely understand that I will not be getting separate ding and dong tones. Right now I am exporting each oscillator into a different audio file so i can hear the ding and dong frequencies separately, then I will build a decay circuit for both so it sounds like the actual ring, and then i need to figure out how to sum them.

A microcontroller could output 2 different frequency pulse trains to a passive RC summing&low-pass filtering circuit (=3 resistors, one capacitor). Both pulse trains could have decaying pulse ratios to make the sound fade gradually in the RC filter. No fine sound coding is needed.
I guess you have reasons why it must be an analog circuit, so software versions are useless. One possibility is to make 2 Wien Bridge oscillators with slightly too small amp gain for continuous oscillation. They will oscillate with decaying amplitude if some initial pulse is given. One possibility to give such pulse is to charge one of the capacitors when the power is turned ON. You must design a sequencer which delays the powering of the "dong" oscillator a while when the rest of the system gets the DC power.
To get it right simulate before building it. As an evidence it can work I show this:


Zoomed image shows the output is quite clean decaying, about 480 Hz sinewave:

The initial kick is got from turning the 9V DC power ON (assuming the initial charges of the capacitors were zero).
The amplifier gain feedback is critical. You see R5 = 20950 ohms. Too small value makes the oscillation continuous and too high value makes the ding too short. R5 must be built by connecting in series or in parallel a fixed resistor and a high quality trimpot.  The usable range of R5 is less than 1% of its value.
The shown circuit should be seen as a starting point for the design, not as a ready to be used construction.
